# Jest + React Testing Library: how do I mock out a method from some library that only affects one test block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

a question for using Jest to mock a method from third party library. so I have a component implemented like this

```js
import {foo} from 'bar'
function Component() {
  // use foo somewhere in the component
}
```

and in the test I tried to mock out `foo` , so

```js
import {foo} from 'bar'

jest.mock('bar')

test('test', () => {
 foo.mockReturnValue(...)
})
```

this works out fine but once I move `jest.mock('bar')` into every individual `test` block, jest would report an error saying that `foo.mockReturnValue` is not a function. like this

```js
test('test', () => {
  jest.mock('bar')
  foo.mockReturnValue(...) //  error: `foo.mockReturnValue` is not a function
})
```

The problem is that, I want to mock out `bar` at every `test` level, not the global level which affects the whole test file. is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to mock out `foo` at every test level, it makes more sense to keep `bar` mocked globally and use `beforeEach()` or `afterEach()` to reset the mocked function before or after each test runs.

```
import {foo} from 'bar';

jest.mock('bar');

afterEach(() => {
  foo.mockReset();
})

test('test', () => {
 foo.mockReturnValue(...);
})
```

You'll want to use `.mockReset()` to remove mocked implementations and return values from `foo`; alternatively, `.mockClear()` can be used if the implementation and return value for `foo` remains the same for each test. Read more on the difference [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockclear).